# Recursively transform object and nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can the below object be recursively transformed, including nested objects, by removing all `edges` and `nodes`? Note that the structure is always the same, meaning edges will always be an array of nodes.

```js
const data = {
  products: {
    edges: [
      {
        node: {
          title: 'x',
          collections: {
            edges: [
              {
                node: {
                  title: 'x - collection'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a helper function `removeEdgesAndNodes`

```js
function removeEdgesAndNodes(obj) {
  return obj.edges.map(edge => edge?.node)
}

removeEdgesAndNodes(data.products)
```

Expected Output

```js
[
  {
    title: 'x',
    collections: [
      {
        title: 'x-collection'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**NOTE**
It is not uncommon for queries to be nested even further, although it does not often go past three levels deep.

For any list, the pattern is always the same. For example, `images` is followed by `edges` and then `node` which contains the properties for each image.

```js
const data = {
  products: {
    edges: [
      {
        node: {
          title: 'x',
          collections: {
            edges: [
              {
                node: {
                  title: 'x - collection',
                  products: {
                    edges: [
                      {
                        node: {
                          title: 'product in x collection'
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Nick's answer is good, he beat me to it! Note I also found this which does the task https://github.com/zeke/humanize-graphql-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.map()` method, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the current object to pull out the `node`/`collections` property from the current object (giving a new object without the `collection` property in a new object called `rest`, in your example this is just an object with `title`, but if you had more properties it would include these also). Which you can then spread into your new object. You can then optionally add a `collections` property to the new object you're creating using object property spread `...` if the current object has a `collections` property using `...(collections && {collections: removeEdgesAndNodes(collections)})`, which will either be a no-op if `collections` is `undefined` (as it is in your inner most object), or it will add the `collections` property to the current object being mapped, with a recursive call your your `removeEdgesAndNodes` function to handle the inner objects:

```js
const data = { products: { edges: [ { node: { title: 'x', collections: { edges: [ { node: { title: 'x - collection' } } ] } } } ] } }

function removeEdgesAndNodes(obj) {
  return obj.edges.map(({node: {collections, ...rest}}) => ({
    ...rest,
    ...(collections && {collections: removeEdgesAndNodes(collections)})
  }))
}

console.log(removeEdgesAndNodes(data.products));
```

You can achieve the same result with a `for` loop and an if-statement, which you might find more readable:

```js
const data = { products: { edges: [ { node: { title: 'x', collections: { edges: [ { node: { title: 'x - collection' } } ] } } } ] } };

function removeEdgesAndNodes(obj) {
  const res = [];
  for (const { node } of obj.edges) {
    const { collections, ...rest } = node;
    if (collections)
      res.push({...rest, collections: removeEdgesAndNodes(collections)});
    else
      res.push(rest);
  }
  
  return res;
}

console.log(removeEdgesAndNodes(data.products));
```

---

To handle dynamic nested object property keys, one approach would be to reconstruct each object. For each `key` and `value` within the input object to your function, you can check the value property for an `edges` property. If it has an edges property then you can map that property to remove the dynamic property name (eg: `collections`/`products`) by recursively rebuilding that object:

```js
const data = { products: { edges: [ { node: { title: 'x', collections: { edges: [ { node: { title: 'x - collection', products: { edges: [ { node: { title: 'product in x collection' } } ] } } } ] } } } ] } }

function removeEdgesAndNodes(obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => [
    key,
    val.edges?.map(({node}) => removeEdgesAndNodes(node)) ?? val
  ]));
}

console.log(removeEdgesAndNodes(data));
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that's very clean. I'm going to study this because I was angry I couldn't figure it out. One thing I might add, I noticed that it works two levels deep. Since these queries can get quite nested it wouldn't be uncommon that it could be a third level down. I will update my comment to show what I mean

Comment: One important detail I missed is that the keys need to be dynamic, for example `collection` is a property of `node`, but maybe we had `featuredImages` instead of `collection`. This is where I was having trouble and things started getting messy

Comment: Hey @dbzx10299, do you know what the nested node keys are in advance (and the order they appear in)? Just wondering how to determine which key to tranform then within a node if it's dynamic? (If you don't know the keys, then would it work to tranform any key that is NOT title, so in your example that would tranform "collections" and then "products" as these are the non-`title` keys in the node? Or do you have other non-title keys in your node so this won't work?)

Comment: I don‘t know the keys in advance since they depend on the query, but the pattern is always the same, if you had `images` then it would be `images { edges {  node { altText src } } }`. 

Anytime there is a list `products` or `images` for example, it‘s *always* followed by edges -> node

Comment: @dbzx10299 I've added another approach at the end of my answer, that should work for dynamic keys

Comment: One thing to note is that title is not important, the only thing that matters is that the edges and nodes are removed.  If you had this query `products { edges { node { title handle images { edges { node { src altText } } } } } }` the returned object would now have for each product a title and handle property which we want, it should be as is, only edges and nodes should be removed

Comment: @dbzx10299 I've added an edit to the last snippet, it's now just concerned with removing the `node`/`edges` properties

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! This turned into a personal challenge that I wasn't able to figure out so thank you for showing me what I should've done